# SQL Survey db - does structure of db allow this?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, survey

I have a survey DB with a certain structure (to allow multiple different surveys in the same DB): each respondent gets one row for each question they answer, instead of one row with multiple columns for each question. Like this:

```
Respondent|Question|Answer|  Broker  | Year |
----------|--------|------|----------|------|
Person1   |    a   |   2  | Broker X | 2018 |
Person1   |    b   |   3  | Broker X | 2018 |
Person1   |    c   |   5  | Broker X | 2018 |
Person2   |    a   |   5  | Broker X | 2018 |
Person2   |    a   |   3  | Broker Y | 2018 |
```

I can run a basic query using 'GROUP BY' to get a table ranking each Broker for each question for 2018. But is it possible, given the above structure to, in the same table, get the results for both 2018 AND 2017 for each Broker? Or is this logically not possible?

Thank you!

EDIT: Sorry, wasnt clear. I would like to get the 2018 score in one column, and the 2017 in another one.

Comment: Add some more sample data, including 2017 rows. Also specify the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: And show the results that you want.  It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Instead of grouping on year, just limit to 2017/2018 in the where clause e.g.

```
GROUP BY Broker
WHERE [Year] in (2017,2018)
```

Comment: Sorry, wasnt clear. I would like to get the 2018 score in one column, and the 2017 in another one.

Answer (score 0):

(edit) I'm assuming 'score' is count of records - if you want to SUM all the 'answers' then replace the `1` with `answer` in the case statements below)

did you mean something like this?

```
select 
  broker, 
  Results2017 = sum(case when Year=2017 then 1 else 0 end)
  Results2018 = sum(case when Year=2018 then 1 else 0 end)
from
  survey
where 
  Year in (2017,2018)
group by 
  broker
order by
  /* this will order by 2018 descending (3rd column) */
  3 desc
```

This should give you:

```
broker  | Results2017  | Results2018
bob     |           2  |           4
Fred    |           6  |           2
Sue     |           4  |           1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I changed the SUM to AVG and made the change to the case statement and I got what I wanted :)

Comment: @Kimbo32 glad to help :)